# Braintree payments payment_method_nonce value is null

Tags: django, braintree

I am working in a **django** application where **braintree** is used for payment purpose. The braintree version I am using is **3.13.0**. I am using the **braintree.js dropin-ui** alongside the braintree app.

I tried to add a payment method using a custom form with fields 'cardholder_name','number' and 'expiration_date'. When I click on the 'Add Payment Method' link, a server-side request is sent to get the client token. Using that I set up braintree as given below :

```
function setup_braintree(){
$.ajax({
        url:'/get_token/', 
        type: 'GET',
        datatype:'json',
        data: {
            payment_freq: 1,
        },
        success: function(d) {
            if (d !== null){
                $('#dropin-container').html('');
                braintree.setup(d.client_token, "dropin", {
                    container: "dropin-container"
                });


            }
         } 
});}
```

My form is as given below:

```
<form name="PaymentMethodForm" id="PaymentMethodForm" action="/payment_method/add/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div id="dropin-container" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id_name_on_card">Name On Card:</label>
      <input type="text" id="id_name_on_card" name="name_on_card" value="" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id_card_number">Card Number:</label>
      <input type="text" id="id_card_number" name="card_number" value=""  class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id_expiration_date">Expiration Date:</label>
      <input type="text" id="id_expiration_date" name="expiration_date" value=""class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    <input type="submit" class="cool-fc button swagbutton" value="Submit" id="submitbutton" name="submitbutton" style="display:none">
  </div>
  </form>
```

As per the documentation,  a 'hidden' field 'payment_method_nonce' is created, but its value is null.

When I submit the form, 'nonce is required' error is being returned. 
What can be the issue here? My server code is given below:

```
result = braintree.PaymentMethod.create({
    "customer_id": request.user.username,
    "payment_method_nonce": request.POST['payment_method_nonce'],
    "number":request.POST['card_number'],
    "cardholder_name":request.POST['name_on_card'],
    "expiration_date":request.POST["expiration_date"],
    "options":{
        "verify_card":True
    }
})
```

Also is there option in dropin-ui to 'add payment method' without using custom form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

For the [Drop-in](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2), you don't need to include any input tags, braintree.js will render an iframe with the form inputs inside the div specified in `braintree.setup(...)`. Then when the user submits this form, the payment method nonce should be available to you server-side.

Your form should simply be

```
<form name="PaymentMethodForm" id="PaymentMethodForm" action="/payment_method/add/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %} 

  <div id="dropin-container"></div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    <input type="submit" class="cool-fc button swagbutton" value="Submit" id="submitbutton" name="submitbutton" style="display:none">
  </div>
</form>
```

If you would like more control over the styling still have the easiest level of PCI compliance, I would take look at [Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thank you for your reply. When a user has a payment method, the dropin-container displays the last added method and 'Change Payment Method' link. I would like to display 'Add Payment Method' form even if user has a payment method. Also I would like to list all the payment methods associated with a customer with option to edit. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user12757 The Drop-in supports adding new payment methods. If the user clicks "Change Payment Method", they will see a link to add a new payment method. They will also see all payment methods associated with their account. They will not be able to edit or remove payment methods here; if you require that functionality I would recommend building a custom integration (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2#custom-integration).